# install apache with development tools

Tags: 12.04, installation, apache2, development, tools

I'm trying to do this http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/04/25/mod_rewrite-and-hiphop-for-php-on-apache-web-server/

But the `yum -y install httpd httpd-devel` gives `-bash: yum: command not found`.

I'm on 12.04.

I already have apache installed.  I just don't know how to get the "development tools".

Please show me how.  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @vasa1 Thanks for looking!  i'm using ubuntu 12.04.  the only article i can find that talks about apache & hiphop running side by side is in the link i provided.  the command comes from that article.  I just want to make this work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919625/hiphop-mod-spdy but this question seems to be the first step

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install apache2-dev` command will install dev packages.

Please note that the `yum` is a package manager for RedHat, Fedora etc.
Equivalent package manager for Ubuntu/Debian is an APT.
Look about `apt-get` command here: [Package Management](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/package-management.html)